# ASP.NET MVC URL Mangling

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My project is creating a middle layer between users and our java API backend to get users' AD groups and use them as an authorization tool while also masking the backend url.

```
routes.MapRoute(  "Catchall",
                  "{*url}", 
                  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                  null,
                  new[] { "HRAuth2" });
```

However, it got even stranger when I logged the start of my home controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (StreamWriter log = new StreamWriter(@"D:\apps\LOGS\hr-authenticator-beta.log"))
        {
            log.WriteLine("authenticator reached." + Request.Url);
        }
        string holder = "";
        holder = getTunneledRequestResult();
        if (holder.Length == 0)
            ViewBag.ToInject = "No data returned";
        else
            ViewBag.toInject = holder;
        return View();
    }
```

The result of this?

```
authenticator reached.https://hr-apidev/favicon.ico
```

In my case, the controller is accessed and should proceed on as normal. While I haven't yet logged every event and call in the program, I know something very bizarre is going on and I don't know what I'm doing to cause it. Where should I start looking?

Comment: `why is one web API call successful, but not the other, ` the reason can be many. May be for the value you passed in fetches 0 records and you might have null reference exception, may be it's not built to process API requests or many other factors.. If you look at the error it is asking you to setup the web config to display your actual error. Give it a try

Comment: The expected result would not be null or zero rows.

Also, exactly how do I set it up for an error I have not the first clue about its nature?

Comment: In the error screen you have posted in the question.. it shows you need to add a line of code in your configuration section under system.web .. It's literally that's all that is needed.

Comment: You wish it had been so easy. Still, question amended.